# How do I put a text on top blinking div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have an element which I set to blink for every 1s indefinitely using the following code:

```
<Row>
   <Col xs="3">
      <div className="alerts-border"> //A Blinking Card code </div>
    </Col>
    <Col xs="3">
       <div> //Card code </div>
    </Col>
</Row>

// CSS:
.alerts-border {
  border: 1px #007BFE solid;
  animation: blink 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% { 
    border-color:#fff ; 
  }
}
```

I wanted to put small text on top of this div which is blinking in order to look something like this:
[image]

I have created a text box for the same using this:

```
<div class="boxed">
  This text is enclosed in a box.
</div>
.boxed {
  border: 1px solid #007BFE ;
}
```

But not sure how to attach this div on top of other div(card which is blinking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

You only set `border-color: #fff` to the `@keyframes` that's why only the border was blinking. You also have to set `opacity: 0` to the `@keyframes` if you want blinking text too.

```css
.boxed {
  border: 1px solid #007BFE;
  animation: blink 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
    border-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <Row>
    <Col xs='3'>
    <div class='alerts-border'>
      <span class='boxed'>10% off on this product</span>
    </div>
    </Col>
    <Col xs='3'>
    <div> //Card code </div>
    </Col>
  </Row>

</body>

</html>
```